# PCSX2 GS plugin failed to open

Tags: drivers, nvidia, pcsx2

I tried running pcsx2 from a couple of different repositories (nooblab and gregory hainut) and I'm getting the same error. "GS plugin failed to open. Your computer may have insufficient resources, or incompatible hardware /drivers." This happened after I changed to my nvidia graphics card because the opensource one was too laggy. PLEASE HELP!